# R won't call gfortran compiled object?

Tags: r, fortran

I made a simple fortran routine

```
subroutine add(x,y)
    real(8) :: x,y

    y = x + 3
end subroutine
```

saved as test.f90.

I compile with

```
gfortran -shared test.f90 -o test.so
```

In R (in the same directory), I use

```
dyn.load('test.so')
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Error in dyn.load("test.so") : 
  unable to load shared object '/Users/Steven/Documents/PhD/npsR/test.so':
  dlopen(/Users/Steven/Documents/PhD/npsR/test.so, 6): Symbol not found: ___addtf3
  Referenced from: /usr/local/gfortran/lib/libquadmath.0.dylib
  Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
 in /usr/local/gfortran/lib/libquadmath.0.dylib
```

Does anyone know why? I'm using mac osx Lion, with R v2.15.0 and gfortran 4.6.2.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you had a look at [F2PY](http://cens.ioc.ee/projects/f2py2e/usersguide/index.html)? Maybe it will help.

Comment: Is this the gfortran from rtools or one that you found somewhere on the internet?

Comment: @AndersGustafsson - Yes, I have, for use with Python, but I'm using R here. I don't think F2py will work with R right?

Comment: @themel - this is gfortran installed from the internet. I tried also compiling using R CMD SHLIB, but it failed, saying that -arch was an unrecognized option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you really understand what you're doing, you should use gfortran that comes with [R tools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/). The missing symbol in libgcc isn't surprising since you're trying to run code compiled with a 4.6 gfortran in a 4.2 runtime environment.

Comment: Thank you, so if I donwload the gfortran in your link, how do I use it instead of the one I have already got? Or will this one overwrite my current one?

Answer (score 2):

You can only use the gfortran version that was used to build R.
Since you are on Lion and presumably have Xcode installed you can get the appropriate version of gfortran from here: http://r.research.att.com/tools/
Go to section: "Apple Xcode gcc-42 add-ons" and choose the appropriate version.

You'll have to get rid of your gfortran 4.6.2 completely or make it inaccessible by changing PATH if possible (which I doubt unless it is in /opt/...).

And do use R CMD SHLIB since that will pass the correct options to compiler and linker.